# WEB API OnAuthorization is Called Twice

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I'm developing web API solution for authorization, we decorated each controller action method with the `BasicHttpAuthorizeAttribute` class with inherits from AuthorizeAttribute.

`public class BasicHttpAuthorizeAttribute : System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute`

For every request, I see OnAuthorization method is called twice. when I check the callstack, all the request is made by same thread/processId. I'm using UnityContainer. I registered by Custom Authorize in WebApiConfig.cs  Please let me know the reason for calling twice.

Comment: Do you have any Preflight CORS Request ?

Comment: Did you ever solve this?  Having a very similar issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you register a filter in webapiconfig.cs it will run for every incoming request.
If you decorate an action with a filter, it will run for that action.
Since you registered the filter and decorated the action, it will run two times.

Comment: Well, I'm experiencing the same issue, and my filter is only used for decorating the action. Is not registered at my webapiconfig.cs so I'm not sure....

Comment: Sorry, I would need a little more information. Does it decorate just the action, or the controller too? Do you have any kind of inheritance(for the controller or filter)? What kind of filter(Authorization, Authentication, Action)?

Comment: It's just the action. But I found some posts suggesting to override the AllowMultiple property to return false, and that worked for me.

Comment: @PedroDrewanz thanks this help me, I had registered my custom Authentication attribute in WebApiConfiig.cs and it was decorated on my 
API controller as well.

Comment: @GonzaloMéndez I have the same issue. Can you post the link or solution example that worked for you?

Comment: @user781700 sorry, that was a long time ago, I don't even have access to the code anymore